# ldap authentication unauthorized

Tags: node.js, ldap

I am trying to authenticate a user using an LDAP client on NodeJS. The client library is passport.

```
var express      = require('express'),
    passport     = require('passport'),
    bodyParser   = require('body-parser'),
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

var app = express();

var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth').Strategy;

var OPTS = {
server: {
    //url: 'ldap://dc02.mydomain.us/DC=mydomain,DC=us',
    url: 'ldap://dc02.mydomain.us',

    //bindDN: 'ldapadmin@mydomain.us',
    bindDN: 'ldapadmin',

    bindCredentials: 'mypassword',
    searchBase: 'ou=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us',
    searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})',
}
};

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res, err) {
res.send({status: 'ok'});
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Using Postman I am posting:

```
localhost:8080/login
Body(JSON): { "username": "myuser","password":"mypassword"  }
```

I get a "401 Unauthorized".

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://dc02.mydomain.us -x -W -D "ldapadmin@mydomain.us" -b "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us" "(sAMAccountName=$userid)"
```

works.

Thoughts?

//**********************************************
working
**********************************************//

```
var OPTS = {
    server: {
        url: 'ldap://dc02.mydomain.us',
        bindDN: 'ldapadmin',
        bindCredentials: 'mypassword',
        searchBase: 'DC=mydomain,DC=us',
        searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{username}})',
    }
};
```

Comment: You got a typo `searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{$username}})'` (the dollar symbol shouldn't be there), maybe it's just a typo in your post but if it's in your code as well it's the first thing to fix. I see also that your searchBase might be an issue, because it points to `CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us`, cn attribute is used for 'leaf objects' (a user entry for example, but not a container like an 'organizational unit' under which you may find users), `ou=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us` would be ok, if you're not sure `DC=mydomain,DC=us` is ok if your directory is not too large.

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks, fixed the typo and recommendation. It will probably help when I get in. :) Is it possible that I have search privileges and not authorization priv?

Comment: @EricLavault Removing CN=users (or ou=Users) did the trick.

Comment: @EricLavault can you create an answer so I can award the points and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in `searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{$username}})'`: the $ symbol shouldn't be there, maybe it's just a typo in your post but if it's in your code as well it's the first thing to fix.

The `searchBase` might be an issue too because it points to `CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us` and the CN attribute is used for 'leaf objects' (a user entry for example, but not a container like an 'organizational unit' under which you may find users), so instead something like `ou=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=us` would be ok, but if you're not sure `DC=mydomain,DC=us` is ok if your directory is not too large.